# problems with loading posts in a table-row

Tags: posts, loop, table

I am trying to modify a code in a webpage.
Currently the page has a table, table-row, table-cell structure where thumbnails which represents posts of a specific category and associated data are loaded using a loop.
Until now we had 10 posts.
I recently added a new one but the shown thumbnails remain 10 and when inspecting the page only 10 posts out of 11 are loaded.
Here is the webpage
http://www.puigciutat.com/museu-virtual/
the posts are the small thumbnails below the render area.

the loop code is

```
<div class="object-selector">
<div class="object-selector-row">
<div class="object-cell-last"></div>
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query('cat=7'); // categoria 7 = objecte
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) { $my_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div id="f_<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "object_file", true); ?>" class="hidden-cell">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="t_<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "object_file", true); ?>" class="hidden-cell">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="i_<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "object_file", true); ?>" class="hidden-cell">
                <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "object_fotogr", true); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="object-cell">
                <a id="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "object_file", true); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(80,80)); ?>
                <div class="object-cell-name"><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?> </div>
                </a>
            </div>                      
            <?php
        } // end while loop
    } // end if

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</div> <!-- object-selector-row -->
</div> <!-- object-selector -->
```

the CSS code is

```
.object-selector {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: table;
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    /*margin: 0 0;*/
    height: 90;
    width: 100%;
}

.object-selector-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;

}

.object-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    /*width: 80px;*/
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.object-cell:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.object-cell-last {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: table-cell;
    width: 5px;
    /*width: auto;*/
}

.object-cell-name {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
```

the weird part is the the width of the object-cell (table-cell) is set automatically even if if try to force to a lower value (I have trying to set it to 80px)

So my main problem is to understand why not all my posts are loaded (I have checked, I have 11 posts), and then when I manage to load them all how to modify my table so I can see them all. I have been trying to put smaller thumbnails but eventually I will have to add another line to the table.

Thank you very much for any help/hint that could be useful.

edit

I have changed the `display:table-cell;` to `display:inline-block;` and got rid of the tables. Now the lines are added automatically.

Comment: If you're going to use `display:table` you might as well use a table, but that isn't the only way to get a grid of items

Comment: '10' is possibly the number set under 'Settings' - 'Reading' - ' Blog pages show at most' because you don't set the 'posts_per_page' in your query.

Comment: @Michael ok,you were right, changing this setting solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```php
$my_query = new WP_Query('cat=7');
```

You asked for posts in the category with the ID 7. You never said anything about how many posts to fetch, so it fetches the default, 10 per page.

So instead, you need to set `posts_per_page`, and you need to set it to a reasonable number such as 50. Bever set it to `-1`, even if you want to show them all, set it to a high number but never `-1`.

Some additional notes:

- Don't use string parsing! `WP_Query( [ 'cat'  => 7 ] )` is a bit nicer, a tiny bit faster, and it allows you to use nested parameters such as `tax_query`. Avoid tutorials that use the string syntax
- The `wp_reset_postdata` should come after the `while` loop, but it should be inside the `if` block. Otherwise there is no postdata to reset!
- If `get_post_meta` fails on any of those IDs it will cause problems. Assign them to variables then check the result and give them default values if they've failed
- Don't hardcode magic numbers like `7`, to be honest you should probably have made a custom post type instead of repurposing a category

Comment: thanks for all the tips, I changed the code to this and now everything is working
`$args = array( 'cat'=>'7', 'posts_per_page' => '50' ); $my_query = new WP_Query($args);`
the two last notes are beyond what I can manage, I can read and modify code, but I am not a coder so writing is a bit more complex for me...

Comment: A custom post type is super super easy, there are even websites that will generate the code for you if you check a few checkboxes and fill out a few inputs for stuff like the name etc. just copy paste the code and resave permalinks and you're done